# Checking things are OK when customizing fitting in tf.keras.Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have the following piece of code, and wonder if fit() functionality is doing things correctly or not. In particular, I have this little check of counting the times train_step() is called, but was expecting (for the example shown below) the output to be the number of epochs and not 2! Anyone can give an explanation? I'm using tensorflow version 2.3.1 :)

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model,self).__init__()
        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(30)
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.count=0

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = tf.nn.relu(self.l1(inputs))
        x = tf.nn.sigmoid(self.l2(x))
        return x

    def train_step(self, data):
        self.count+=1

        x,y = data
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            tape.watch(self.trainable_variables)
            preds = self(x)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y,preds) #+ tf.reduce_mean(tf.squeeze(self(inputs))-labels)*reg
            grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_variables))
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y,preds)
        return {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
    
inpus=tf.random.uniform((100,1))
labels = tf.ones((100,1))
network = Model()

network(inpus)
network.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=10**-2), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
network.fit(x=inpus,y=labels,batch_size=len(inpus),epochs=100)

print("\nfinal count: {}".format(network.count))
```

Thanks a lot !